# How to stop Android Studio from copying files when adding module?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I have 2 android projects: Tower and dronekit-android. I try to import both projects into Android Studio at the same time. So I first import Tower, then import dronekit-android in the project setting window. (Using File -> Project Structure -> +)

However, The Android Studio did something very unusual, namely, it always copy all source codes from the other project into the root directory of the current project. As illustrated in the following screenshot, in which all folders shown in the diff window are copied from dronekit-andorid to Tower.

[image]

How do I change this behaviour and import them without copying? Like in this:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I tried to modify my settings.gradle to include the other project with submodules:

```
//Android projects
include ':Android'
project(':dronekit-android').projectDir = new File('/home/peng/git-drone/dronekit-android')
```

but I can't import it due to this error:

```
Error:Project with path ':dronekit-android' could not be found.
```

is there anything wrong with the setting?

**UPDATE2:** I eventually edit setting.gradle manually and add the other project & all its submodules into it, take quite some time I was expecting Google Android Studio is smart to do it automatically:

```
//Android projects
include ':ServiceApp', ':StarterApp'
include ':ClientLib'

//Library projects
include ':Mavlink'
include ':UsbSerialLibrary'

project(':UsbSerialLibrary').projectDir = new File('dependencyLibs/usb-serial-for-android/UsbSerialLibrary')
project(':Mavlink').projectDir = new File('dependencyLibs/Mavlink')
project(':StarterApp').projectDir = new File('samples/StarterApp')
```

But then I got into another problem:

When I synchronise the project, I got this error:

```
Error:Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.bintray' not found.
```

Please see the screenshot for detail:

[image: Error:Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.bintray' not found.]

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include `:dronekit-android`:

```
include ':Android',':dronekit-android'
project(':dronekit-android').projectDir = new File('<fullpath>/<projectname>/<module folder>')
```

And in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':dronekit-android')
}
```

Comment: You are right! Now I can see the files in the project window. But I got into a problem that never happens when importing either of the project independently. Is it a version conflict?

Comment: Not really, this is really how you import from local directory since your library module might have a similar name to other other modules (though that's a rare case).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to include another project into the one (without copying things over) you can add an entry in the "settings.gradle" file to specify the project name and where on the file system the project is (relative path is ok):

```
project(':project-name').projectDir = new File('path-to/project-name')
```

After doing this you just need to import the "main" project (the one with the modified settings.gradle).

Comment: Apparently doesn't work: Error:Project with path ':dronekit-android' could not be found. see my update for detail.

Comment: What's the directory structure under dronekit-android? The path should be to the module and not the root project (i.e. the path should point to the build.gradle with the "android" configuration)